# Is there any way I can make automerge work without upgrading to webpack 5?

Tags: webpack-4, automerge

I'm trying to use Automerge ( https://automerge.org/) in a Reactjs project. As described in Automerge's document, with webpack 5, to setup automerge, we need to enable "experiments.asyncWebAssemby".
Unfortunately, the project I'm working on is using webpack 4 (4.28.3) and "experiments" is not available on that version.

Is there any way I can make automerge work without upgrading to webpack 5 ?
Thankyou all for the help!

Automerge document:
https://automerge.org/docs/quickstart/

module.exports = {
experiments: { asyncWebAssembly: true },
target: 'web',
...};

Answer (score 1):

You can by installing wasm-loader. It is deprecated but works pretty fine if you are using webpack 4.

https://github.com/ballercat/wasm-loader